# How to pin the whole array in C# using the keyword fixed

Tags: c#, fixed, unsafe

Does the line `fixed (int* pArray = &array[0])` from the example below pin the whole array, or just `array[0]`?

```
int array = new int[10];
unsafe {
    fixed (int* pArray = &array[0]) { } // or just 'array'
}
```

Comment: i think no. you have to do `fixed (int* pArray = array)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, no, that won't work: `CS0208 Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('int[]')`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque dont put `&` before `array`. just write `(int* pArray = array)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, good point. This way it works.

Comment: Some additional advice from Mr. Lippert: [What’s the difference? fixed versus fixed](http://ericlippert.com/2009/08/27/whats-the-difference-fixed-versus-fixed/) and [Taking responsibility](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/11/taking-responsibility/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following statement:

```
fixed (int* pArray = array)
```

will fix the **complete** array. Proof can be found in the [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (Section 18.6 *The fixed statement*, emphasis mine):

> A *fixed-pointer-initializer* can be one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - An expression of an array-type with elements of an unmanaged type T, provided the type T* is implicitly convertible to the pointer type given in the fixed statement. In this case, the initializer computes the address of the first element in the array, and **the entire array is guaranteed to remain at a fixed address for the duration of the fixed statement.** ...

---

The following statement:

```
fixed (int* pArray = &array[0])
```

fixes **the address of the first array element**. Again, a quote from the specification (from an example found in that chapter):

> ```
> ...    
> [third fixed statement:] fixed (int* p = &a[0]) F(p);
> ...
> ```
>
> ...and the third statement **fixes** and obtains the address of **an array element**.

---

Side note: I would assume that any sane implementation that fixes the *first* element simply fixes the whole array, but the specification does not seem to guarantee it.

Digging a bit deeper into the example code in the specification reveals the following:

> ```
> ...    
> [third fixed statement:]  fixed (int* p = &a[0]) F(p);
> [fourth fixed statement:] fixed (int* p = a) F(p);
> ...
> ```
>
> The fourth fixed statement in the example above produces a similar result to the third.

Unfortunately, they do not specify what exactly they mean by "*similar result*", but it is worth noting that they did not say "*same result*".